# Decorrelation of a singular autocorrelated variable

Tags: autocorrelation

I have a dataset with several variables with average prices from week to week over many years. The problem is that each variable autocorrelates with itself heavily and I want to decorrelate variable for variable each by itself so that I can actually use different statistical tests and actually get meaningful answers on each variable. But I am having trouble finding what type of technique or methods I can use to achivie this type of decorrelation since the variable autocorrelates differently based on time. So for example it heavily autocorrelates week for week, but for each week going by it autocorrelates less and less. So I checked first out PCA, but that doesn't do that, I got mentioned mahanalanobis decorrelation, but I am having a bad time actually finding how to perform that decorrelation in excel, stata or python. So if anyone have any teqnique or methods to share that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi: some time series  models account for autocorrelation so there's no need to de-correlate. for example, a lagged dependent variable model is one.

Comment: @mlofton This time time series models doesn't account for autocorrelation unfortunately, do you have any suggestion for how to proceed?

Comment: Hi: Can you write your model down and explain the variables. I say this because, in time series modelling, it's often the case that a variable is related to its previous value(s) so the last thing you'd want to do is uncorrelate them. I might not be able to help but writing it explicitly may allow others to help ?